# How can I use grep to display lines WITHOUT either of two specific strings?

Tags: text-processing, grep

For a large logging file, how do I display those lines without "success" or not terminated with "ok"?

Comment: `grep -Ev '(success|ok$)'`

Comment: @jordanm was going to suggest the same. This is an answer though and should be put in the right section.

Comment: @jordanm terrific, please make it an answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To remove lines that contain **either** string, specifically with grep:

- In one command, per jordanm's comment:

  ```
  grep -Ev 'success|ok$'
  ```

  or:

  ```
  grep -ve success -e 'ok$'
  ```

  or:

  ```
  grep -v 'success
  ok$'
  ```
- In two commands:

  `grep -v success file | grep -v 'ok$'`

Example:

```
$ cat file
success something else
success ok
just something else

$ grep -Ev 'success|ok$'
just something else
$ grep -v success file | grep -v 'ok$'
just something else
```

To remove lines that contain **both** strings, specifically with grep:

```
grep -v 'success.*ok$' file
```

Example:

```
$ cat file
success something else
success ok
just something else

$ grep -v 'success.*ok$' file
success something else
just something else
```

Comment: if jordanm wants to answer instead, I'll delete this one.

Comment: No, this is fine.

Comment: Lee, I see you've accepted this answer, but I want to clarify - these greps will remove lines that contain **either** of those two strings; did you want to remove only lines that contain **both** "success" and end with "ok" ?

Comment: No. either, not both.

Comment: thanks for clarifying; take a look at the most recent edit to your question to make sure it says what you meant.

Comment: That's amazing that an OR `|` factors out to a PIPE `|`!!

Answer (score 2):

I would try awk

```
awk '/success/ { next ; } /ok$/ { next ; } { print ;}' file
```

where

- `/success/ { next ; }` find word `success` and skip line
- `/ok$/ { next ; }` find lower case `ok` and skip line
- `{ print ;}` implicit else : print line

as per suggestion

short awk (thanks to Stéphane Chazelas )

```
awk '!/success/ && !/ok$/'
```

which is basically not (success) and not (ok at end of line )

golfed awk (thank to cas )

```
awk '! /success|ok$/'
```

which reuse regexp, and negate it

Comment: Even if this works, that's not an answer to the question.

Comment: Yes, it's an alternative way.

Comment: @Lee: it's not an alternative. It does not fulfill the condition "use grep to."

Comment: @QuoraFeans I understand what you mean. You both are right at your points.

Comment: `awk '!/success/ && !/ok$/'` would be more canonical.

Comment: @QuoraFeans - there's nothing wrong with providing alternative methods as answer....especially when (not the case here) the OP's question asks about using the wrong tool for the job.  In this case, `grep` is a good tool, but so is `awk`, and it's always good for people to learn that not only are there multiple valid ways of doing most tasks, but also HOW to do those tasks with several different tools.

Comment: or even `awk '! /success|ok$/'`

Answer (score 0):

Since awk was mentioned, another alternative would be sed:

```
sed '/success/d;/ok$/d' file
sed -e '/success/d' -e '/ok$/d' file
```

or (Newer sed and future POSIX) thanks to Stéphane Chazelas

```
sed -E '/success|ok$/d' file
```

Comment: If you change `sed -r` to `sed -E`, then that will work in some BSD `sed` in addition to (not too old versions of) GNU `sed`. `sed -E` will be in the next major issue of the POSIX spec.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to grep -Ev commands above:
You can use `egrep -v 'success|ok$' filename`

Comment: `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E`